# Dividir um string com espaços vazios

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando dividir uma entrada do seguinte tipo:

```
1444771699,Andre Alves,SAQUE,-500.00,,200
```

Estou tentando usar o `strtok`, mas ele ignora o espaço vazio. Alguma ideia de como dividir a string sem ignorar o espaço?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Coloque mais informações na pergunta assim fica melhor para a comunidade ajudar vc, por exemplo, mostre a string que vc recebe como entrada e mostre a saída que vc deseja. Também sugiro que vc faça um tour para aprender como perguntar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "ignorar" o espaço? Isso significa que os "pedaços" vêm com o espaço, mas deveriam vir sem, ou seria o contrário? Ou você se refere ao trecho que não tem nada (i.e. entre as duas vírgulas)? Por favor diga o que exatamente quer, o `strtok` parece que pode resolver, se chamado com os argumentos certos. Sugiro [edit] a pergunta mostrando como você fez, o que obteve, e o que esperava obter.

Answer (score 0):

Da pra você formatar a string caractere por caractere.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = "1444771699,Andre Alves,SAQUE,-500.00,,200";
    int qtd = 1;

    printf("string %d: ", qtd);
    for (int i = 0; i <  strlen(s); i++){
        if ( s[i] != ',')
            printf("%c", s[i]);
        else if ( s[i] == ',') {
            qtd++;
            printf("\nstring %d: ", qtd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O método strtok, serve para fazer a quebra de uma string, depois de passar a sua string uma unica vez por parâmetro, basta colocar `NULL ou 0` no primeiro parametro, assim o método irá retornando as partes da string. Use `string.h`

```
char *buff = "minha string com espaço";
char *word = strtok(buff," ");
int x=0;
while(word){
    puts(word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A função `strtok` acaba por separar uma string em "pedaços", ou `tokens`, de acordo com alguma expressão utilizada.

Protótipo da função: `char* strtok(char* str, const char* delimiters);`

Portanto, uma solução simples para o seu problema seria algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char string[] = "1444771699,Andre Alves,SAQUE,-500.00,,200";
    printf("String: %s\n", string);
    char* token;
    token = strtok(string, ",");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Considerando a sua entrada como `1444771699,Andre Alves,SAQUE,-500.00,,200`, a execução do código acima resultará na saída abaixo
`1444771699
Andre Alves
SAQUE
-500.00
200`

Você poderá então alocar a saída abaixo em uma matriz de strings caso seja necessário conforme sua aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Sabendo quais campos podem não receber valores entre as vírgulas poderia fazer uma leitura específica para esse campo, veja um exemplo usando `sscanf` para ler os dados de uma string contendo a entrada que você forneceu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char s[] = "1444771699,Andre Alves,SAQUE,-500.00,,200";
    char buffer1[100],buffer2[100],buffer3[100],buffer4[100];
    double d;
    int n, b;

    sscanf(s, " %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%lf,%n", buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, &d, &n);
    if(s[n] == ',') {
        buffer4[0] = '\0';
        sscanf(s+n+1, "%d", &b);
    }
    else {
        sscanf(s+n, "%[^,],%d", buffer4, &b);
    }
    printf("%s \n%s \n%s \n%lf \n%s \n%d \n", buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, d, buffer4, b);


    return 0;
}
```

Note que como já sabemos que o 5º campo separado por vírgula pode ser vazio ele não é lido no primeiro sscanf, e checamos primeiro se ele está vazio antes de ler, e se estiver vazio atribui string vazia no `buffer4` e pula a próxima vírgula (`s+n+1`) para ler o 6º campo.

Answer (score -1):

Suponho que o problema sejam os campos vazios, que o `strtok()` não reconhece. No Linux, temos a função `strsep()`, que foi criada justamente para resolver a limitação do `strtok()`:

```
#include <string.h>
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
```